# Как отправлять сообщение по Id?(Vk_api)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Можно ли отправлять сообщение через бота определённому человеку, если у другого человека(с другого аккаунта) ввести команду?
Например: человек вводит /test и отправляет. Бот это видит и отправляет сообщение администратору. Администратор видит ссылку на человека, который отправил запрос и переходит

Делаю пока-что тестовую функцию. Обрывок кода:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import random
import time
token = ""
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)


def write_msg(user_id, message):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, "random_id": 0})

longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            msg = event.text
            if msg in hi_word:
                write_msg(event.user_id, random.choice(hi_otvet))
            elif msg == "Тест":
                write_msg(event.user_id, "отправленно")

                write_msg(event.user_id, "отправленно от...") #тут должно отправлять сообщение на id(не в чат, где это было введено)
            else:
                write_msg(event.user_id, "Ошибка. Я вас не понимаю")
```

p.s Вырезал лишнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как отправлять сообщение по id?

Вы и так отправляете сообщение по `id`. Вам просто нужно передавать идентификатор администратора вместо идентификатора пользователя.

***Пример:***

```py
ADMIN_USER_ID = ...

write_msg(ADMIN_USER_ID, "отправленно от...")
```